# Use separator other than / in sed

Tags: sed

I want to use `sed` on some text that contains backslashes, and want to avoid lots of escaped `\/` characters.

How can I change the delimiter or separator character to be other than `/`?

Answer (score 0):

In GNU `sed`, simply swap out the `/` for the character you wish to use:

```
% echo /// | sed 's_/_x_g' 
xxx
```

`\` can also be used, and must not be escaped (it fails when escaped as `\\`):

```
% echo xxx | sed 's\x\y\g'
yyy
```

Comment: Yes, it is encouraged. Sorry I missed the duplicate.